# ng required does not work for "NaN" value according to docs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have checked the solutions and I did not get explanation. I doubt that it is a bug. (I may be wrong, but I dont have explanation why it does not work. )

When scope variable has value NaN, "ng-required" does not work as expected in docs. i.e. It should set "required" error for that input.

Here is the plunker link.
https://plnkr.co/edit/mAwpBwyYE1kfXEb3az9p?p=previhew

Documentation link:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$isEmpty

HTML

```
 <div data-ng-controller="demoController">
  <h3>Ng Required Does not work for NaN Value </h3>
  <h5>Documentation : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$isEmpty</h5>
  <p style="color:blue;">According to docs =>  The default $isEmpty function checks whether the value is undefined, '', null or NaN.</p>

  <form onsubmit="javascript:return false;" novalidate id="testForm" name="testForm" data-ng-submit="submitTestForm()">
    <p>Undefined Value Test for "ng Requried"</p>
    <input id="undefinedValue" name="undefinedValue" data-ng-model="undefinedValue" data-ng-required="true"/>
    <span data-ng-show="testForm.undefinedValue.$error.required" style="color:red">Required</span>

    <p>Null Value Test for "ng Requried"</p>
    <input id="nullValue" name="nullValue" data-ng-model="nullValue" data-ng-required="true"/>
    <span data-ng-show="testForm.nullValue.$error.required" style="color:red">Required</span>

    <p>NaN Value Test for "ng Requried"</p>
    <input id="nanValue" name="nanValue" data-ng-model="nanValue" data-ng-required="true"/>
    <span data-ng-show="testForm.nanValue.$error.required" style="color:red">Required</span>


    <p></p><button type="submit">Test With Ng Submit </button></p>
    <p><button data-ng-click="submitTestForm()" type="button">Test Without Ng Submit</button></p>
  </form>

</div>
```

Javascript

```
angular
  .module('demo',[])
  .controller('demoController',['$scope', function($scope){

      // Initial Data
      $scope.undefinedValue = undefined;
      $scope.nullValue = null;
      $scope.nanValue = NaN;

      // Submit test form handler
      $scope.submitTestForm = function(){

        if($scope.testForm.$valid !== true)
        {
          return false;
        }

      };
  }]);
```

My Questions are, 
1. Why it is not working as explained in docs,
"The default $isEmpty function checks whether the value is undefined, '', null or NaN.".
2. Why it works when form is submitted through "ng-submit". Error is shown after ng submit function executes.

I hope the plunker explains the problem.

Comment: Don't you need to encapsulate your `input` fields in `md-content` tags ?

Comment: Any reason u are not accepting my answer?

Answer (score 0):

What actually happens is that the ng-required on input["text"] which is the default type of input checks for the $viewValue length for being 0,
So for NaN that value is not 0. (what is it? I tested, results a head) while for null and undefined the condition is length == 0 is false.

When you submit, the NaN actually clears and becomes null, therefore the "required" is shown.

As you can see in the docs of ng-required: 
[Ng-Required](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired)

I've actually wanted to test it so I created a directive which logs the test "is length ==0" and I got for the first two exception and the last... false! :) (funny when i log the $viewValue I get 'undefined')

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0CDWbLVseQmkKzJRZWcZ?p=preview)

```
.directive('testValue', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      template: '',
      scope: {},
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ngModelCtrl) {
       scope.$watch("nanValue", function(){
          console.log(ngModelCtrl.$modelValue.length===0) ;
       });
      }
  };
});
```